# Need to insert into table using return table results. I'm not able to insert only select

Tags: sql, function, insert, plpgsql

I am unable to use the multiple records from the returns table function and insert into another table.  I can call the function and return the results, but can't insert.

```
``
with rst as (select * from audit.audit_tbl_row_count_by_year(sch,tbl,fld) a)
              insert into audit.audit_metric_data(level,value) values(a.yr,a.cnt);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.audit_tbl_row_count_by_year(sch text, tbl text, fld text)
RETURNS TABLE (
      vyr int,
      vcnt numeric
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE 
    qry text;
    var_r record;
    --could not get RETURN QUERY to use parameters
BEGIN
  qry := 'select extract(year from '|| fld ||') as yr, count(*) as cnt from '|| sch ||'.'|| tbl ||' group by 1';
   FOR var_r IN EXECUTE qry
   LOOP
        vyr := var_r.yr ; 
        vcnt := var_r.cnt;
        RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END$$; 
``
```

The following code is working

`for rec2 in select * from audit.audit_tbl_row_count_by_year(sch,tbl,fld)
       loop
         insert into audit.audit_metric_data(metric_id,level,value,run_date) values(rec.metric_id,sch|| '.' ||tbl|| '.'||fld|| '.' ||rec2.vyr,rec2.vcnt,current_date);

       end loop;`

Comment: What is your RDBMS and version? And what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`. You're way off that. You may try:

```
INSERT INTO audit.audit_metric_data
            (level,
             value)
            SELECT vyr,
                   vcnt
                   FROM audit.audit_tbl_row_count_by_year(sch,
                                                          tbl,
                                                          fld);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  The issue is that our version of GPDB doesn't support running functions at the segment node directly.